# Random with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm

I have the following code to extract records from a `dbcontext` randomly using `Guid` class:

```
var CategoryList = {1,5};
var generatedQues = new List<Question>();

//Algorithm 1 :)
if (ColNum > 0)
   {
    generatedQues = db.Questions
          .Where(q => CategoryList.Contains(q.CategoryId))
          .OrderBy(q => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(ColNum).ToList();
   }
```

First, I have a list of `CategoryId` stored in `CategoryList` as a condition to be fulfilled when getting records from the `db`. However, I would like to achieve an even distribution among the questions based on the `CategoryId`.

For example:

If the `ColNum` is 10, and the `CategoryId` obtained are `{1,5}`, I would like to achieve by getting 5 records that are from `CategoryId = 1` and another set of 5 records from `CategoryId = 5`. If the `ColNum` is an odd number like 11, I would also like to achieve an even distribution as much as possible like maybe getting 5 records from `CategoryId 1` and 6 records from `CategoryId 2`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Evenly divide the total by the number of categories, increasing some of them by 1 to get to the final total if you have a non-divisable number. If you want 10 questions from 4 categories you will need to get 3+3+2+2. So first divide Nq by Nc getting the lowest number of questions per category. Then calculate the remainder of Nq/Nc (10/4 remainder = 2), and increase the first X such numbers by 1. 10/4 gives 2+2+2+2, but the remainder of 10/4 is 2, so increase the first two numbers by 1 giving 3+3+2+2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two step process,

1. Determine how many you want for each category
2. Select that many items from each category in a random order

For the first part, define a class to represent the category and how many items are required

```
public class CategoryLookup
{

    public CategoryLookup(int catId)
    {
        this.CategoryId = catId;
    }

    public int CategoryId
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public int RequiredAmount
    {
        get; private set; 
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        this.RequiredAmount++;
    }
}
```

And then, given your inputs of the required categories and the total number of items required, work out how many are required for each category

```
 var categoryList = new []{1,5};
 var colNum = 7;

 var categoryLookup = categoryList.Select(x => new CategoryLookup(x)).ToArray();
 for(var i = 0;i<colNum;i++){
     categoryLookup[i%categoryList.Length].Increment();
 }
```

The second part is *really* easy, just use a `SelectMany` to get the list of questions (Ive used a straight linq to objects to test, should work fine for database query. `questions` in my code would just be `db.Questions` in yours)

```
var result = categoryLookup.SelectMany(
      c => questions.Where(q => q.CategoryId == c.CategoryId)
                    .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                    .Take(c.RequiredAmount)
 );
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/RHF33878

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var CategoryList = {1,5};
var generatedQues = new List<Question>();

//Algorithm 1 :)
if (ColNum > 0 && CategoryList.Count > 0)
{
    var take = // Calculate how many of each
    // First category
    var query = db.Questions
            .Where(q => q.CategoryId == CategoryList[0])
            .OrderBy(q => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(take);

    // For all remaining categories
    for(int i = 1; i < CategoryList.Count; i++)
    {
        // Calculate how many you want
        take = // Calculate how many of each
        // Union the questions for that category to query
        query = query.Union(
            query
            .Where(q => q.CategoryId == CategoryList[i])
            .OrderBy(q => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(take));
    }
    // Randomize again and execute query
    generatedQues = query.OrderBy(q => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList()
}
```

The idea is to just get a random list for each category and add them all together. Then you randomize that again and create your list. I do not know if it will do all this on the database or in memory, but it should be database I think. The resulting SQL will look horrible though.

Comment: I think the `take` was really the crux of this question, no?

Comment: I thought both the splitting parts and how to get the question list were the issue. You can find lots of answers for splitting a number into even parts already, so I did not bother with that.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Mats391 as well !!